# Trouble with footer

Tags: css, footer

Hey I'm learning HTML and CSS and have had succes with footers before, but for some reason this particular project keeps giving me problems with the footer no matter what I try.

I have some floating elements, and have used a wrapper to put them in.

What I want is a Footer that sticks to the bottom of the page at all times. Regardless of content or scrolling behavior.

When I do this, for some reason the footer sticks to the **top of the wrapper** even though I positioned it outside of the wrapper element in the HTML coding.

```css
#footerBottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: black;

}
```

```html
<div id="header">
 <title>The Title Of The Website</title>

</div>
<nav>
</nav>

<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="contentLeftOne">

 </div>

 <div id="contentLeftTwo">

 </div>

 <div id="contentLeftThree">

 </div>

 <aside id="sideTop">

 </aside>

 <aside id="sideMiddle">


 </aside>

 <aside id="sideBottom">

 </aside>

</div>

<div id="footerBottom">
 <p>Here Is A Footer But It Isn't Sticking To The Bottom</p>
</div>
```

When I position it inside the wrapper, it's positioned at the top of the wrapper element.

Am I overseeing something? I googled a bunch but nothing seems to solve it. Do I need to use jQuery? Is it the floating elements that's screwing things up?

Thanks in advance for all that try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your HTML a bit to help get you started.

For valid HTML, make sure that your `li` elements are children of a `ul` (or `ol`) element.

Also, `<title>` is not a valid HTML tag. However, `title` is a valid attribute for some HTML tags.  The `<title>` tag is used for metadata as part of the document `<head>` section, for more details, see: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element;

Note that since you are using `position: fixed` for the `#footerBottom`, that element will be taken out of the content flow and positioned with respect to the viewport.  `#footerBottom` could appear anywhere in your script and the it would get positioned in the position specified by your CSS rule.

```css
#footerBottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
#wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 4.5em; /* or else you can see it beneath the footer... */
}
#wrapper, nav {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
#wrapper div {
  min-height: 25px;
  background-color: beige;
  margin: 10px 100px 10px 0;
}
#wrapper aside {
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 25px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h3>The Title Of The Website</h3>
</div>
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Page1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="contentLeftOne"></div>
  <div id="contentLeftTwo"></div>
  <div id="contentLeftThree"></div>
  <aside id="sideTop"></aside>
  <aside id="sideMiddle"></aside>
  <aside id="sideBottom"></aside>
</div>

<div id="footerBottom">
  <p>Here Is A Footer But It Isn't Sticking To The Bottom</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok great, thanks. So far not at least the < p> text is showing inside of the footer. Didn't know I needed to use UL for the nav. It's still sticking to the top though, it might be because I'm using CSS in the other elements on the page. Your code works perfectly. instead of wrapper div {} i'm using the #wrapper ID i made for the DIV, is that ok? 

I thought TITLE as an HTML5 tag, thanks I fixed that now.

Comment: Also, now that I am seeing your code. I CSS'd it very differently. instead of using #wrapper div I have been using #NameOfDivID for everything. is that ok?

Also the wrapper is not respecting the margin-bottom I am giving it. Something is messed up, I might have to start over and this time start with the footer instead of the content.

Comment: (1) The text in the `p` in the footer is showing because I set the color to white to contrast with the background color. (2) The `nav` (and children `ul` and `li` elements) are towards the top because that is where they appear in your HTML document. (3) `#wrapper div` means style the `div`'s that are descendants of the `#wrapper` element.   (4) If you have additional CSS rules, they will affect the layout.  My CSS is for demonstration only.

Comment: If you have floated elements, then other issues could arise.

Comment: Yeah i need a bit more reputation before I can do this but i will remember to come back.

Answer (score 1):

The normal flow of HTML is to start at the top and go to the bottom. Your footer is positioned at the bottom but the p element is only one line box high. So it starts at the top of your footer as it should. If you set the height of your footer to a smaller height than 4em, you'll see the difference. Or, for that matter, set the font size or line height to 4em and see what happens.